# What are these bunch of non-existence methods in material button google reference?

Tags: java, android, android-button, material-components-android

I tried to change material button icon programmatically and for this, Stackoverflow posts suggest that there is a frangible method called `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`.

I tried to find more methods on the official sites e.g. [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com) and GitHub, But oddly I find methods and XML-attributes that do not exists at all.  For example [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#attr_MaterialButton_icon) suggests the following:

[image]

As I know, There is no `app:MaterialButton_icon` nor `android:MaterialButton_icon` attributes for XML. Also there is no `setIconResource(int)` method (in Java 8).

What are these odd reference documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is that highlighted `MaterialButtom_icon` attribute but it seems that you are using `Button` instead of `MaterialButton` in your java code. The correct declaration of material button is as:

```
MaterialButton button = findViewById(R.id.your_material_button_id);
```

And **Not**

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.your_material_button_id);
```

By the correct declaration then we have:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The names that you see on the official site are just custom styleable attribute names which is used for that View.

You can learn more about it in this link: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view#customattr

In XML, you can just simply use `app:icon="@drawable/icon"` instead of `app:MaterialButton_icon="@drawable/icon"` for example.

If you cannot find those methods in the code, please check your project dependencies to make sure it has Google Material dependency. Or if you are using Kotlin, the method like `setIcon` or `getIcon` is simply `icon` property without any functions.

Hope this can resolve your problems